# jQuery - on window scroll run a function without any delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I have an issue with a jquery function. You can see a working demo here - http://dev.sreejesh.in/menuissue/ . As you can see when the user scrolls down to the page, I have written a jQuery function(which will triger on scroll) to check scroll pixel. When the browser scrolls to a certain pixel(height of the sidemenu block), the Menu block will stay fixed & rest of the content scrolls as normal.

The functionality is working now, however the problem is menublocks makes a jumps when this function runs. I think this is because of the delay in running the function. Hope you guys have any nice trick to fix this.

I used an if/else function to check the scroll pixel, so when the scrolled pixel is greater than menublock height it will add a class "fixed" .

I use the following code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="globalwrapper">
    <div id="menubar">
       ---- Menu List items-----
    </div>
    <div id="mainblock">
        ----Main content area----
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       adjustScroll();
    });
});

function adjustScroll(){
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var menublockHeight = $('#menubar').height();
    var scrollValue = $(document).scrollTop();
    var posValue = menublockHeight - windowHeight;

    var menuStatus = $('#menubar').css('left');

    $('#menubar').css('minHeight', windowHeight);
    $('#menubar').css('height', menublockHeight);

    console.log(menuStatus);

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if(menuStatus == '0px') {
            if(scrollValue > posValue){
                $('#menubar').addClass('fixed');
                $('#menubar').css('marginTop', -posValue);
            }else {
                $('#menubar').removeClass('fixed');
                $('#menubar').css('marginTop', '0px');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think only CSS can solve this issue, add this style:

```
#menubar{
    position: fixed;
}
```

just test on Google Chrome,you can have a try.

Comment: Nope. I already use class "fixed", which have property position:fixed.   Problem is jquery makes a delay in applying class.

Comment: I mean use this property directly, not via javascript

Comment: I need to make the menublock fixed only after scrolling certain pixel. So I can not avoid javascript.